# Calulating date difference in minutes by using HQL/SQL query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, date, timestamp

I have a field of time Timestamp in my MySQL database which is mapped to a date datatype in my Bean.
Now I want a query by which I can fetch all records in the database for which the difference between the current timestamp and the one stored in the database is > 20 minutes.

How can I do it?

What I want is

```
select T from MyTab T where T.runTime - currentTime > 20 minutes
```

I tried the following

```
Query  query =  getSession().createQuery("Select :nw - T.runTime   from MyTab T");
  query.setDate("nw", new Date());
```

It returns some values like -2.0110930179433E13 .

How can I model this in SQL/Hibernate?
Even if I get some native SQL query (MySQL) then it's ok.

Comment: see [TIMEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-unctions.html#function_timediff)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this link might help:

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2393545

and this one is also very helful:

[Hibernate Dialects + datediff function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4606807/225396)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like no other way.