# How to get Date Difference in hour using HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, date, hql

I've to get difference between current date and the date stored in database in hours. In PostgreSQL, I'm able to do it using the following query:

```
SELECT storage_time, extract(epoch from (localtimestamp - storage_time))/3600 as diff_hour FROM some_table;
```

This gives me the difference between dates in hour:

```
      storage_time       |     diff_hour      
-------------------------+-------------------
 2014-02-03 19:37:39.481 |  44.4788805811111
 2014-02-03 19:40:28.201 |  44.4320139144444
 2014-01-29 18:25:12.828 |  165.686284192222
 2014-02-03 19:25:56.861 |  44.6740528033333
 2014-02-05 15:53:38.178 | 0.212575858888889
 2014-01-30 15:53:38.61  |  144.212455858889
```

Now, I'm facing difficulty porting it to Hibernate Query Language. I've tried many variations, but I'm unable to get *epoch* from date difference. This certainly doesn't work:

```
"FROM SomeEntity " +
"WHERE someAttribute = :attr " +
"AND epoch(localtimestamp - deviceInfo.storageTime) / 3600 > :threshold_hour";
```

When I run this command, I get following exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2040)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1837)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1275)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
```

I ran the query like this:

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .getNamedQuery(GET_NON_EXPIRED_ENTITY)
                    .setString("attr", attr)
                    .setInteger("threshold_hour", thresholdHour);

List<SomeEntity> instances = query.list();
```

Exception is coming at 2nd line, when I call `list()`.

But, when I change `epoch()` function to `day()`, in hibernate query, it runs without exception, but of course with unexpected result.

Is there any way I can get the same behavior of PostgreSQL query in HQL?

Comment: I tried doing something like this a while ago I seem to remember and gave up. As far as i recall there is no API in HQL to do something like this - you need to resort to native SQL...

Comment: @BoristheSpider :( :( That is really sad. :(

Comment: Maybe some hibernate Guru will come along and suggest some clever HQL construct. There's always hope!

Comment: Just as a clue for another way to phrase your searching, what you're doing is converting an SQL timestamp to a "unix timestamp," "epoch seconds", or a "julian date" variant, i.e. seconds since the epoch. I know JPA and JPQL / Criteria lack support for the `interval` type, so HQL probably does too, but they might provide something as basic as converting a timestamp to seconds. Though I always ran into Hibernate limitations as soon as I used it for much "real work", so maybe not...

Comment: @CraigRinger So, currently there is no workaround apart from moving to native SQL?

Comment: @RohitJain A quick search suggests you can hack it together from the date extraction functions. http://whyjava.wordpress.com/2010/04/18/hql-which-gives-no-of-hours-bw-two-timestamps/, http://stackoverflow.com/q/639522/398670 . Ugly, but workable.

Comment: Or [register your own function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606807/hibernate-dialects-datediff-function), but this also sounds somewhat painful.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I guess that would be too much of a work. I'll use the native query only.

Answer (score 1):

1. HQL [supports](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-expressions) EXTRACT(... FROM ...) function, and EPOCH keyword although it is not mentioned in documentstion.
2. HQL also supports no-argument LOCALTIMESTAMP function (for Postgres and MySQL dialects). This fact also is not in documentation, but I found it in sources ([link1](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL81Dialect.java#L144), [link2](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLDialect.java#L161))

So, required HQL query is:

```
FROM SomeEntity p 
WHERE EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (LOCALTIMESTAMP-p.storageTime))/3600 > :threshold
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. No EPOCH function in mySQL and the generated MySQL query is broken and doesn't work

Comment: The question clearly asks about postgresql, not about mysql

Comment: The title clearly talks about HQL, the answer clearly talks about HQL, so one would expect this solution to work also in mySQL, which is not the case.. so I think it is important helping people to spare the time of trying to understand why it doesn't work for them in mySQL..